# IIS WebApi unable to open connection to Remote Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm unable to make any database calls from my WebApi. I get the exception: "Underlying provider failed to Open."

I have a c# WebApi that's hosted on a Windows Server 2016 under IIS v10.0.14393.0. Then I have a SQL Server 2016 database running on a different Windows Server 2016. Whenever I try to make an api call that wants to connect to the database I get the exception. When I host the WebApi on my local IIS however I get no errors.

**Question:** Why does the remote Api not connect to the remote Sql Server?

Some configurations I have already made are:

- **Sql Server**: Allows remote connections is checked
- **Sql Server**: Sql Server & Sql Server Browser Services are Running
- **Sql Server**: Firewall has an Inbound rule with Protocol Type: TCP, Local port: 1433 and Scope Remote Ip Address: [WebApi server address]
- **WebApi Server**: WebApiApplicationPool & DefaultAppPool are running under the standard ApplicationPoolIdentity

Other info:

- Both machines are able to ping each other.
- My connection string uses a database account for authorization.

Inner Exception

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
```

Comment: No chance your webserver has more than 1 IP? watch the firewall fails and see whats hitting it. Check also SQL is listening on port 1433 as that hasnt been default for a while now

Comment: ipconfig says the webserver only has 1 IP address. Sql is listening on port 1433 for IP2 and IPAll. I can't find anything 'weird' in the logs for the firewall.

Comment: Do you see even the attempted connection?

Comment: I'm looking under Microsoft -> Windows -> Windows Firewall With Advanced Security -> Firewall in Event Viewer and there are no new events when I make a call.

Comment: Most likely it's a problem with the DNS.

Comment: i thought that except it was pingable suggesting same name used.. are the machines on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

That error you are having is a exclusively connection problem. You have to check on yout SQL Server that you have TCP/IP protocols enabled and that the IP you are using to connect also is enabled. This is a typical problem when trying to connect to SQL Server since on SQL Express this is disabled by default.

You can take a look on how to do that in here: https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/stories/insights/2015/tcpip-is-disabled-by-default-in-microsoft-sql-server-2014

And here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port